# IndexNotFoundException versus NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code that attempts to catch a null reference. It then throws an exception with a clearer reason for the error specified in the message property.

What type of exception **should** it throw? An `IndexOutOfRangeException`?

```
var existing = this.GetByItemId(entity.ItemId); // int or long
if (existing == null)
{
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("The specified item does not exist.");
}

var price = existing.Price;
```

or a `NullReferenceException`?

```
var existing = this.GetByItemId(entity.ItemId);
if (existing == null)
{
    throw new NullReferenceException("The specified item does not exist.");
}

var price = existing.Price;
```

or, should we have just let the exception run its course?

```
var existing = this.GetByItemId(entity.ItemId);
var price = existing.Price; // NullReferenceException coming your way
```

The reason we tend not to do this last option, is that the default NullReferenceException is light on detail and just states

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Which, to be honest, could quite well be the most unhelpful error message in C#.

Comment: From your code, `IndexOutOfRangeException` does't seem to fit: I expect such exception when accessing an indexable structure (array, list) with in integer index, and the index used is out of range.
your `GetItemById(int itemID)` seems to use an id of something for a lookup, not an integer as index

Comment: is the `existing` null or is the`existing.Price` null, quite different things that would be. Your examples indicate it both ways however.

Comment: If you lack details in the null reference exception, perhaps you'll want to inherit it and create your own exception with the properties you need? Or just any old custom exception with some informative description, that's probably what I'd do...

Comment: In these case, I usually go with a custom `mySpecializedException` (if I want the caller to be able to handle it in ad hoc way), or a generic `ApplicationException("The specified item does not exist.");` if the only thing I do with that exception is log and tell the user "sorry, something went wrong"

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss the `existing` object is null.

Comment: I'd use `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: If that `entity.ItemId` is not a valid index what would YOU expect by description - is the number not pointing to a valid entry? Data returned from some repository etc.  That will tell you how to handle it by your expected and need of that result. in `this.GetByItemId(entity.ItemId);` for example is `this` null here as well?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss this in this case is a method in the same class that gets an element by its Id from a repository for example. The key here is that if I let the code continue without checking the `existing == null`, I would get a NullReferenceException by default. Instead I'm catching it and providing the user with a more appropriate error message.

Comment: By convention, NRE and others are always considered bugs. All experts agree on this, to a novice it might seem like an arbitrary rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use a custom exception for this (some thing like `ItemNotFoundException`).

A `NullReferenceException`or `IndexOutOfRangeException` might be thrown by something else inside of `this.GetByItemId()` or in the Framework somewhere.

The caller might wish to perform a follow up action if the item does not appear in the collection (e.g. adding it). 
Using your own exception allows the caller to `catch` that exception specifically and react accordingly.

Comment: I have taken your advice. We now have a ItemNotFoundException.

Answer (score 5):

A custom exception with the description of your choice should do it:

```
 if (existing == null)
    {
        throw new EntityMissingException("'existing' does not exist (ironic, isn't it?).");
    }
```

Comment: Never throw the base class of all Exceptions. This makes it impossible to write focused catch blocks.

Comment: I am honestly interested in why this is downvoted =) The OP argues that the NullReferenceException is "light on detail". Using a custom error text can provide lots ant lots of detail, if required. Agreed, it has drawbacks when it comes to handling etc, but is it really that bad? I tend to do this a lot, so I'll truly appreciate pointers as to why it is bad, I'm not just ranting because I got downvoted! =)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. I should have went with the not quite as quick and dirty custom error instead, you're probably right.

Comment: I already explained it in my comment above. The problem is not the custom error message - which is great! - but that you are throwing an instance of `Exception`. This rule is derived from another rule: Never catch `Exception`. Instead, catch a more specific exception class. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137.aspx) for an explanation. Now, when you throw `Exception` - instead of a more specific exception class - you force the user of your code to write a catch block that violates the rule to never catch the base class `Exception`.

Comment: @Daniel: Your comment wasn't visible when I wrote mine. Thanks for further details and links!

Comment: You are welcome. It's good to ask for clarification, when you don't understand the reason for a downvote. Just like now it can help change your answer into a great one and you might just learn something new :)

Answer (score 1):

The `NullReferenceException` indicates that you want to access a member of a null reference. Normally you should never throw it (unless if you implement an interpreter or something similar).

If the `entity` is a parameter, then I would say this is an `ArgumentException`. If you say that this should never happen in normal circumstances, then this is rather an `InvalidOperationException`.